# Workflow find item in another list

Tags: workflow

I try a workflow on a list when item is created or modified : 
http://puu.sh/jfQwF/8a01a9f9b1.png

Then I update item in another list.
But it's not working, I think it don't find any item : 
http://puu.sh/jfQyx/e4f46ce236.png

Comment: My list A : 
http://puu.sh/jfQGp/5b4193cdd7.png
My list B :
http://puu.sh/jfQFl/dbb46c90c8.png

Comment: If I'm right in understanding you, You are trying to update second list based on first list column. If so, have a look on this article https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/210353ac-d383-417a-9840-235953f962cb/how-do-i-update-on-field-on-second-list-using-sharepoint-designer?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

Comment: How you are trying to find item?